# Sorting an array is not working

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Can someone please let me know what's the problem with the below code?
Am trying to sort an array stored in "Options" variable. But it throws 'Null' exception.

```
public static void CheckOptionsPresent(String s1) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        List optionsList=null;     
        webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance button")).click();
        int listcount = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li")).size();
        System.out.println(listcount);
        String[] options=new String[listcount];

        for (int i=2; i<=listcount; i++ )
        {
            options[i-1] = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child("+i+") a span")).getText();
            System.out.println(options[i-1]);
        }

        System.out.println(options.length);

        for(int j=0; j<options.length;j++)
        {
            for (int i=j+1 ; i<options.length; i++)
            {
                if(options[i].compareToIgnoreCase(options[j])<0)
                {
                String temp= options[j];
                options[j]= options[i]; 
                options[i]=temp;


                }
            }

            System.out.println(options[j]);
        }
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
14
AB - Alberta
BC - British Columbia
MB - Manitoba
NB - New Brunswick
NL - Newfoundland and Labrador
NS - Nova Scotia
NT - Northwest Territories
NU - Nunavut
ON - Ontario
PE - Prince Edward Island
QC - Québec
SK - Saskatchewan
YT - Yukon Territory
14
```

**Below is the error:**

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

---

```
for (int i=j+1 ; i<options.length; i++) {
    if(options[i].compareToIgnoreCase(options[j])<0) {
        String temp= options[j]; options[j]= options[i];
        options[i]=temp; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post the error message and where it is happening

Comment: post the line number where error is happening or post the stack trace

Comment: Why not use Collections.sort() in stead of writing your own sorting?

Comment: Below is the error : org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.                                                                                                                                             for (int i=j+1 ; i<options.length; i++)
            {
                if(options[i].compareToIgnoreCase(options[j])<0)
                {
                String temp= options[j];
                options[j]= options[i]; 
                options[i]=temp;
                }
            }

Comment: It is not going into the above for loop.

Comment: That's an exception thrown by the Eclipse debugger, not your code.

Comment: There is a null in the array so Collections.sort() will also throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.compareToIgnoreCase()` does not like `null` as its argument.

After your first loop, `options[0] = null;`

A `NullPointerException` happens when this gets hit on the first pass of `if(options[i].compareToIgnoreCase(options[j])<0)`then the indexes are `(i = 1, j = 0)`.

Comment: Yes Mark. Actually, am writting a generic function for our project and all the dropdown contains a null value.That is the reason even collections.sort(optionsList) is not working for me. Could you please let me know how do I remove null values from the array/list other than "optionsList.removeall(collections.singleton(null)); " .... thanks for the help.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to use a(n) (Array)List instead of an array and only include non-null values then Collections.sort() should work for fine.  When you've sorted everything insert a null at the 0-th index.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Mark. i have got another logic from my friend and its working fine. Posted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code :

```
public static void CheckOptionsPresent(String s1) throws Exception {
    try {
        List < String > optionsList = null;
        webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance button")).click();
        int listcount = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li")).size();
        System.out.println(listcount);
        String[] options = new String[listcount];

        for (int i = listcount; i >= 2; i--) {
            options[i - 1] = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child(" + i + ") a span")).getText();
            System.out.println(options[i - 1]);
            optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);

        }
        System.out.println(optionsList);
        System.out.println(isSorted(optionsList));

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static boolean isSorted(List < String > list) {
    boolean sorted = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == null) continue;
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) > 0) sorted = false;
    }

    return sorted;
}
```